# Conflict of college and prayer time

Tags: salat, prayer-timings

I have a problem.. I have to go to college at lets just say 6pm-9pm every weekday. And we can assume magrib is at 6.20pm and isha 7.20pm.. I can come back and do Isha prayer but how can I do magrib prayer.. Can I do it before going to college or can I perform it after coming home? Can u tell me what I should do?

Comment: You can't pray a prayer before it's actual timing unless you are traveling (and for specific prayers only). Is there anything that hinders you leaving the lesson for 5-10 minutes to pray?

Comment: I usually leave the lesson for a few minuted to pray if a class coincides with the prayer time.

Answer (score 1):

You don't have a choice to skip the salah at all, so you must do it at all costs. Inshallah Allah will help you find a way.

Some solutions are:

1. See if you can excuse yourself from class
2. See if it is okay to come late; some college class start a little later than usual
3. You can do wudhu at home, and then pray on a chair
4. Find any other Muslims in your class and maybe make a prayer group

If none of these work, find another solution and ask Allah for his guidance

Comment: Welcome to Islam.SE! Please check out a [tour](https://islam.stackexchange.com/tour) of our site to learn more about how this site works. Thanks for the answer.